# Displaying Images in SSRS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on SSRS (RDL Reports) with MVC 3. In some of the Reports, I need to display the images whose path is specified in the Database. I have tried binding the full path to image control used in SSRS but its not displaying the images.

Can anyone suggest some pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image properties set

```
Source: External
Value: "file:" & Fields!imagepath.Value // replace with your database path column
```

Normally now it will work  (tested with network path \myserver\sharedfolder\filename.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Im am running a report out of visual studio 2010 on my development machine. The image file is on the same machine as visual studio.

nableExternalImages = true;

Implementing the previous suggestion in the expression property looks as follows :

="file:" & Fields!PhotoA.Value, "ImageDataSet" 
or 
=("file:" & Fields!PhotoA.Value, "ImageDataSet")

these both produce an error.

my syntax in the expression property is :
=First(Fields!PhotoA.Value, "ImageDataSet").

NO error is produced but there is no image in the image box on the report.

I have another image box with an embedded image in it. The path for the embedded image is the same is that produced by  =First(Fields!PhotoA.Value, "ImageDataSet"). This embedded image appears in both development and at run time but the external image does not.